# Changing the build intermediate paths for gitlab-runner

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, gitlab

I have a server pointed as ab12.xy24.com in which the projects are placed as:

```
 Path-1  
 /home/ab12/public_html/project1/*  
 /home/ab12/public_html/project2/*  
 ................................
 /home/ab12/public_html/projectn/{project-files}
```

I am using gitlab-runner for CI and CD. The build is being built as:

```
 Path-2  
 /home/ab12/build/{runner-token}/{commit-id}/{group-name}/project1/{project-files}
 /home/ab12/build/{runner-token}/{commit-id}/{group-name}/project1/{project-files}
```

I want the build path to be as in Path-1 style instead of path-2 style.

---

What have I tried?

I tried changing the `build_path="path1"` variable which only changed:

```
/home/ab12/build/{runner-token}/{commit-id}/{group name}/project1/{project-files}
```

to

```
/home/ab12/path1/{runner-token}/{commit-id}/{group-name}/project1/{project-files}
```

I cannot also use docker as due to its virtualization concept and takes much space, which is not desired.

Comment: As far as I know you can't (to avoid race conditions between 2 builds). But if you're sure of uniqueness of builds,  a symlink from path1 to path2 in the before section should do no?

Answer (score 10):

Conceptually, this approach is not the way to go; the build directory is not a deployment directory, it's a temporary directory, to build or to deploy **from**, whereas on a shell executor this could be fixed.

So what you need is to deploy from that directory with a script as per `gitlab-ci.yml` below, to the correct directory of deployment.

```
stages:
- deploy

variables:
  TARGET_DIR: /home/ab12/public_html/$CI_PROJECT_NAME

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
     mkdir -pv $TARGET_DIR
     rsync -r --delete ./ $TARGET_DIR
  tags:
    - myrunner
```

This will move your `projectfiles` in /home/ab12/public_html/

naming your projects as `project1` .. `projectn`, all your projects could use this same `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

Comment: can you please explain its working for files handled with .gitignore... How would '''rsync help this'''

Comment: @Wildfire not sure if I understand the question. `.gitignore` is used for your local tree, meaning items in `.gitignore` are not committed ( git commit ), thus also not pushed to the git repository and thus also not present in the `CI_PROJECT_DIR`.

Comment: I am quite sure you know my question. my last comment has just my illusion... thanks